# Wordpress on localhost doesn't show pictures loaded via FTP in different directory than uploads

Tags: php, wordpress, image, ftp, localhost

I am migrating 100GB of pictures from an old program to WP in localhost (WAMP 3.0.6). I have uploaded the whole directory in WP within a plugin ('/wp-content/my-plugin/photo_dir/') and I have associated each image to its user using usermeta.

What is weird is that although any pics gives a 404 error (even when I copy-paste its url on the browser), If I load the same picture using media library or my own ajax function (which puts the file in the same directory '/wp-content/my-plugin/photo_dir/') the pic is regularly shown.

My own ajax function uses wp_upload_bits with a redefine UPLOAD_DIR.

```
// Set custom setup.
                add_filter( 'upload_dir',   'derm_upload_viso_dir' ); // path override.

                    // WordPress will move the file to a differente directory.
                    $upload = wp_upload_bits($fileName, null, file_get_contents($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"]));
                // Set everything back to normal.
                remove_filter( 'upload_dir',    'derm_upload_viso_dir' );
```

I tried to change permission on the folder (which I can't).
I thought I had to 'register' the image as a post but wp_upload_bits doesn't do that and it shows fine after.

Anyone can help?

Comment: I have added another file via ftp and compared it to the others using is_file and is_readable. It looks like the problem lies in each image not being seen as 'existing'.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can define a new upload directory by adding

```
define('UPLOADS', 'images/uploads');
```

at the bottom of your `wp-config.php` file.